# np.where return error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (0,) (0,)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to learning numpy. I write the statement as follows to count the number of Buy and Sell, but doesnt work.

```
count = np.where(((df.Buy == 1) & (df.Sell== 0)),  count + 1, count)
```

and return error message:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (0,) (0,)
```

Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: what is the initial value of `count`

Comment: The count is a list, and update the list if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to count how many times Buy == 1 and Sell == 0 at the same time. One way to do this is:

```
count = ((df.Buy == 1) & (df.Sell== 0)).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this as well:

```
count = df.query('(Buy == 1) and (Sell == 0)').shape[0]
```